# Olingo Odata - How to create CsdlProperty of type Collection<String>?

Tags: java, rest, odata, olingo

Like in title. I have in code something like that:

```
CsdlProperty property = new CsdlProperty().setName("test").setType()
```

Whats the type for `Collection<String>` ? Is this a complex type if yes can someone provide any example ?
Cannot find anything about that in documentation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
`CsdlProperty property = new CsdlProperty()
.setName("test")
.setType(EdmPrimitiveTypeKind.String.getFullQualifiedName())
.setCollection(true);`

Comment: Yea i figured it out after looking at csdl model with "type=Collection(...Type.String)", but thanks either way.